# How do I use in_array with Laravel QueryBuilder output?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When I use laravel's DB query builder, it returns an array like:

```
array(20421) {
  [0] =>
  class stdClass#887 (2) {
    public $color =>
    int(1)
    public $size =>
    string(6) "141793"
  }
```

I'm comfortable working with Laravel collections but this isn't a collection since I'm not using eloquent (and dont want to be in this case). My question is, how can I check to see if a record exists in this array where color = 3 and size = 123?

Comment: Any reason why you need to retrieve 20k+ records and then figure out if one exists?

Comment: I'm inserting new data that needs to insert a new one, or update an old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just wrap the result in a Laravel collection and use it like you are used to:

```
$result = DB::table('...')->get();
$collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($result);

$exists = $collection->contains(function($key, $value){
    return $value->color == 3;
});
```

---

If you have to worry about performance you might want to use this instead though
(or maybe even run a db query instead?)

```
$exists = ! is_null(array_first($array, function($key, $value){
    return $value->color == 3;
}));
```

The collection internally uses `array_first` as well (which just loops over the array until a match is found) but without the collection you should be able to improve performance a bit. However, I can't tell if it will be noticeable.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way to check if exists in the result?

Comment: How would you do it with the collection? `contains()` with a closure?

Comment: first() with a closure, but contains would probably be better since I don't need the record itself, just a boolean.